# Using Velocity's stagger option to delay animations

Tags: jquery, animation, velocity.js

I am trying to use Velocity.js's `stagger` option while applying an animation to a collection of elements. I would expect that each element would be animated with a slight delay from the previous in order that they don't all fade on at the same time. Unless I am misunderstanding how to use it.

Do you know why this is not working?

```
$('DIV').velocity({ opacity: 1 }, { stagger: 900, duration: 400 });
```

Demo here:

https://jsfiddle.net/louiswalch/o85qnp69/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

CSS:

```
DIV {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('DIV').velocity("fadeIn", { stagger: 900, duration: 400 });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o85qnp69/6/)

Comment: Stagger doesn't work with opacity? It's been a while, but I am pretty sure I needed opacity for this use-case because they needed to take up DOM space when invisible rather then shifting the DOM when appearing.

Comment: I am not sure what is the case with opacity and velocity effects. But I tried using these effects with opacity in one of my projects and it didn't work.